# Steam and Teamspeak not connecting, but internet in general is working fine?

Tags: steam, technical-issues, teamspeak

So I logged on today, and realized Teamspeak was not connecting to the server I log on to every day. I had also realized Steam was having a tough time connecting to the internet, and I have no idea what's happening.

- I tried restarting my router with the expectation it would work, it didn't.
- I have no new antivirus programs
- Firewall was turned off for about 2 hours, I tried again and no result.
- Pinged Google.com, got an average approximate round trip time of 65 ms.

No errors were given when trying to connect to Steam or Teamspeak.

The funny thing about this is that all functions are carried out normally that require internet. Everything else that requires internet works just fine.

I have another machine (a laptop) that runs Teamspeak and Steam just fine, so I'm guessing it could be something to do with the connection specifically on my primary machine?

Edit (3/4/15): Tried using Windows troubleshooting and it couldn't identify that anything was wrong. I have absolutely no clue what to do.

Comment: These are two wholly unrelated things. You haven't provided enough information to answer what your problem is. That's because it requires a lot of back and forth and troubleshooting. This question is not suited for this site.

Comment: Does Steam/Teamspeak throw an error message or show an error code at all? Can you access the internet normally, by hitting Google or other big sites? What sort of lag time are you getting when running a ping request to google.com or other big sites? Do you have any new antivirus programs, firewall settings or other programs that may interfere with your connection? Sorry, we're gonna need a lot more info to go on before we can help you diagnose the problem

Comment: No error codes at all from Teamspeak or Steam, and no antivirus programs that are new. Firewall doesn't interfere with any other incoming or outgoing connections, and I turned it off, tried, still no result. Average ping time was 65 ms, 4 packets sent, 4 received, none lost. Hope that's good enough info.

Comment: @MustafaAhmedani - Thanks for that, I've voted to reopen your question. This might be a silly thing to ask, but have you restarted your primary machine recently? There's potentially a pending update or something that's stuffing it up.

Comment: @Robotnik yep, three times yesterday, twice today. No clue. No driver updates (according to Windows)...

Comment: What happens when you try to connect? You say you get no errors. Do the programs just say connecting forever, or do they close themselves? Have you tried reinstalling Teamspeak and Steam?

Comment: Have you checked to see if the Steam and Teamspeak ports are open?

Comment: @raznagul, it says "Failed to connect to server". As I stated earlier, it works fine on my laptop.

Comment: @RobertRose what ports would those be?

Comment: Have you tried to ping steampowered.com and the ip of your teamspeak you use? I would check your hosts file for anything maybe malicious (maybe you made enemies with someone? maybe upset a family member?) to check your host file go to C:/Windows/System32/Drivers/etc/ and open the "hosts" file and just look for something that looks like "127.0.0.1    steampowered.com" or the ip to your teamspeak and if there is something like that in there you can remove those lines, save the hosts file to your desktop (cause it wont let you save it back into the "Etc" folder, then drag the file back into "etc"

Answer (score 3):

Assuming windows, based on your description.

Try the following:

1. Click on the Start menu/screen, click search.
2. Type: **CMD**
3. **Right-Click** Command Prompt and click **Run as Administrator**
4. Confirm the UAC prompt when it comes up.
5. When you have an *Administrator: Command Prompt* window, Execute:

   - **ipconfig /flushdns**
6. Click **Restart** from the Start menu/screen and perform a FULL reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I'd had the same issue:

I found out that a day before I logged in, my IP Address and Firewall level was set to high. Upon restarting,  my modem the issue occurred. Changing the level back is what resolved it for me.